# unable to click each other repeatedly

Tags: javascript

Hard to explain in human language, just show the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang='zh-CN' xml:lang='zh-CN' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function call_f1(){
            document.getElementById('f1_div').click();

            // document.getElementById('f1_div').click();
        }

        function f1(){
            console.log('f1 '+new Date());               
            document.getElementById('btn_1').click();                
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn_1" type="button" onclick="call_f1()" value="callf1"></input>
    <div id="f1_div"  onclick="f1()" style="background: red; width: 35px; height: 35px;">
    </div>
</body>
```

When you click the button using your mouse, you get a single output on the console. Why?? Doesn't `f1` function invoke repeatly?

Comment: Firstly why would you want to do this, secondly why not use a loop if all you want is the date being logged?

Comment: Are you sure that a *div* has *click()* method? What your console says about?

Comment: @Lame-up-duck All HTML elements should have the `click` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Doesn't work for me, only get a single output to the console (rather than the repeated outputs I'd expect). What browser are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I had misinterpreted the question, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?? Doesn't `f1` function invoke repeatly?

No. [`.click()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-click) and the [synthetic click activation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps) it starts won't do anything when there's already an active `'click'` event for the element.

> 1. If the element's *click in progress* flag is set to true, **then abort these steps**.
> 2. Set the *click in progress* flag on the element to true.

If you want it to be continuous with `.click()`, you'll have to allow the previous event to finish first. Probably with the use of a timer:

```
function f1(){
    console.log('f1 '+new Date());

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('btn_1').click();
    }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps
So, add timeout to the two functions call. As below.

```
    var timeout = 0; // change this to whatever suites for you
    function call_f1(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('f1_div').click();
        }, timeout);

        // document.getElementById('f1_div').click();
    }

    function f1(){
        console.log('f1 '+new Date());               
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('btn_1').click();
        }, timeout);                
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
   function call_f1(){
        document.getElementById('f1_div').onclick();

        // document.getElementById('f1_div').onclick();
    }

    function f1(){
        console.log('f1 '+new Date());               
        document.getElementById('btn_1').onclick();                
    }
```

This one is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/djhell/rG782/

Comment: Looks like either Firefox or jsFiddle is detecting the infinite recursion and stopping it, but definitely works.